# Состояние загрузки для каждой кнопки отдельно

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент формы. Имеет следующее состояние:

```
this.state = {
    isLoading: false
}
```

Т.е. если форма ждет ответа от сервера, то состояние `isLoading` меняется на `true`.

Код формы (урезан):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" />
    <Button isLoading={this.state.isLoading} label="Одобрить" />
    <Button isLoading={this.state.isLoading} label="Отклонить" />
</form>
```

Форма имеет две или более компонентов кнопок. При нажатии на какую-либо кнопку данные инпута отправляются на сервер и форма переходит в состояние загрузки (`isLoading` меняется на `true`).

Когда кнопке передан `isLoading=true`, то текст кнопки меняется на `Загрузка...`.

Проблема в том, что при `isLoading=true` СРАЗУ У ВСЕХ кнопок меняется текст (что, собственно, абсолютно нормально), а должно только у той, которую нажали.

Вопрос: как просто и изящно сделать так, чтобы текст менялся только у той кнопки, которую нажали, при условии, что кнопок может быть много и они не должны создаваться в цикле?

Залил все на пен для экспериментов [CodePen](https://codepen.io/misha-saidow/pen/pQmjqW)

Comment: Создать кнопку отдельным компонентом, у которого будет свой `state.isLoading`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko были идеи. Но как кнопка поймет, когда менять текст на `Загрузка` и когда возвращать назад, если запрос на сервер идёт в компоненте `Form`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взял за основу ваш код, приведенный на CodePen и немного дополнил его своей идеей. Возможно не самое лучшее решение, но оно имеет место быть, итак, к коду:

```js
const Button = props => {
  return (
    <button
      id = {props.id}
      type = "button"
      onClick = {props.onClick}
    >
      {props.isLoading ? "Загрузка..." : props.title}
    </button>
  );
};


class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      clickedButtons: [],
    };

    this.handlers = {
      loadData: (event) => {
        const { id } = event.target;
        const { clickedButtons } = this.state;
        clickedButtons.push(id);
        this.setState({ clickedButtons }, () => {
          // данные якобы пришли
          setTimeout(
            () => {
              const { clickedButtons } = this.state;
              const newСlickedButtons = clickedButtons.filter(btnId => btnId !== id);
              this.setState({ clickedButtons: newСlickedButtons });
            },
            3000);
        });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "Не важно" />
        <Button 
          id = "btn-1"
          onClick = {this.handlers.loadData}
          isLoading = {this.state.clickedButtons.includes("btn-1")}
          title = "Кнока 1" 
        />
        <Button 
          id = "btn-2"
          onClick = {this.handlers.loadData}
          isLoading = {this.state.clickedButtons.includes("btn-2")}
          title = "Кнока 2" 
        />
        <Button 
          id = "btn-3"
          onClick = {this.handlers.loadData}
          isLoading = {this.state.clickedButtons.includes("btn-3")}
          title = "Кнока 3" 
        />
        <Button 
          id = "btn-4"
          onClick = {this.handlers.loadData}
          isLoading = {this.state.clickedButtons.includes("btn-4")}
          title = "Кнока 4" 
        />
        <Button 
          id = "btn-5"
          onClick = {this.handlers.loadData}
          isLoading = {this.state.clickedButtons.includes("btn-5")}
          title = "Кнока 5" 
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Form / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
form {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

form>* {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Что же тут особенного - это хранение в стейте массива кликнутых кнопок в переменной `clickedButtons`. Изначально массив пустой. Но, потом, после каждого клика на кнопку - будет добавлен идентификатор этой кнопки в массив кликнутых, затем, с помощью замыкания мы пробрасываем внутрь функции, которая выполняется по таймауту, наш идентификатор кнопки и с помощью обычного фильтра убираем кликнутый ранее айдишник из массива. Обратите внимание, что функция на получение данных лежит в колбэке метода `setState` - это гарантирует нам наличие положенного айдишника кнопки. Зачем в колбэке использовать - просто потому что `setState` метод выполняется асинхронно и данных может не быть, а выполнение в колбэке гарантирует нам наличие положенных ранее данных в `state`.

Данный пример - всего лишь идея, не обязательно завязываться на `id`, вы точно так же можете использовать и другой аттрибут, только желательно, чтобы он отличался у кнопок. Конечно, если кнопок на форме будет не так уж много - можно сделать отдельные переменные на каждую кнопку, но это уже на ваше усмотрение. Также, из рекомендаций - советую быть аккуратным при вызове `setState`, дабы не вызвать мутацию состояния `state`, что может привести к странному поведению.

В коде использовал два простых метода JS:

- [**`Array.prototype.filter()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - для фильтрации массива
- [**`Array.prototype.push()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) - для добавления нового элемента в массив

Comment: Довольно изящно и масштабируемо - то, что нужно.

Comment: @MishaSaidov ну, *изящно* - это громко сказано. А так, рад помочь 