# Как в React вызвать обновление страницы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Имеется кусок кода на реакте. Там где звёздочки проблема. Состояние кнопки обновляется только при обновлении страницы. `setState` не совсем подходит, т.к. из мапы видно, что если использовать `setState` то приментся ко всем элементам. Какое решение может быть?

```
this.props.requestStore.requests.map(({id: request_id, state, book, user}) => (
    <tr key={request_id}>
        <td>
            <input type="button"
              value="Удалить"
              className="request-req-inp-del"
              onClick={() => this.delete(request_id)}
            />
            <input type="button"
              value="Одобрить"
              className="request-req-inp-app"
              onClick={() => this.approve(request_id)}
              disabled={**!book.state**}
            />
        </td>

        <td>{state ? "Запрос выполнен" : "На рассмотрении"}</td>
        <td>{book.title}</td>
        <td>{user.username}</td>
        <td>{user.bookGiven - user.bookTaken}</td>
    </tr>
)
```

Comment: Я тут недавно давал ответ на похожий вопрос: [Состояние загрузки для каждой кнопки отдельно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/915707/189339) Ознакомьтесь, думаю будет полезно.  Можно сделать массив где будет храниться переменная для каждой кнопки.

Comment: @DenisBubnov суть в том, что в массиве 10 книг. По каждой проходим и рисуем кнопки. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии кнопки сразу считывали изменившиеся состояние и применяли дизейбл, но это происходит (сейчас) только если перезагрузить страницу, т.е. пройтись по массиву заново. Кликая по одной кнопке, мне необходимо блокировать другую.

Comment: @DenisBubnov всему виной моя невнимательность и поверхностные знания React. Ошибку нашёл, спасибо Вам за помощь, Вы навели на мысль)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалась на поверхности. Дело в том, что в своем Store я не додумался менять состояние в массиве. Происходила такая ситуация: кнопка нажималась, в бд изменения шли, но в массиве, который на фронте хранится в данный момент, я не менял состояние.
Решение:

```
changeState(identity) {
        const request = this.requests.find(({id}) => id === identity);
        ...
        
        for (let obj of this.requests) {
            if (obj.book.id === request.book.id){
                obj.book.state = false;
            }
        }

        return request;
    }
```

Где,

> request - текущая запись (в ней расположена кнопка), на которую была
> нажата кнопка;
>
> identity - id этой записи, по которой можно было быотследить;
>
> this.requests - массив записей для прохода;
>
> obj.book.state - все записи, которые относятся к одной книге.

Также я немного изменил вызов массива, по которому проходил.